# Counterexample and hint to solve question 4 page 23 in Do Carmo's differential geometry book

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

I'm trying to solve this question in the classical [Do Carmo's differential geometry book](http://www.math.uni.lodz.pl/~maczar/ggk/do%20Carmo,%20Differential%20Geometry%20of%20Curves%20and%20Surfaces.pdf) (page 23):

> Assume that all normals of a parametrized curve pass through a fixed point. Prove that the trace of the curve is contained in a circle.

My counterexample is parts of circles with different radii:

[image]

Am I right? If not, I need a hint to solve this question.

*Remark*: Please don't give me solutions, I already have them.

Comment: Your counterexample cannot be parametrized: because parametrization describes a curve as the image of a continuous map from $\mathbb{R}$, any parametrized curve must be connected.

Comment: Have a look at the definition of parametrized curve in page 2.

Comment: @Neal yes, because the interval in connected, the image (trace) must be connect also, right?

Comment: @mfl I have, thank you. Do you have any hint to solve this question? thank you

Comment: If you choose the fixed point to be the origin, then the condition that the trace of $\gamma$ lies in a circle centred on that point is equivalent to $|\gamma|^2$ being constant. How could you show this?