# Why can a fixed point be written as a linear combination of curve if all normals pass through the fixed point?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

In one of my tutorials, we got the following question:

"Assume that all normals of a parametrized cuve pass through a fixed point. Prove that the trace of the curve is contained in the circle" (Do Carmo, differential geometry of curves and surfaces).

I was stuck on this, and got the hint that the fixed point part implies that, for every $s$, there exists a $r(s)$ such that the fixed point, denoted by $P$, can be written as a linear combination of $\alpha(s)$ and $\alpha ''(s)$, i.e.

$P= \alpha(s) + r(s)\alpha''(s)$.

From this point, I have been able to solve the question (by differentiating etceta). However, why is the latter statement true? Is there a geometrical or algebraic explanation why this holds?

Comment: Here it is assumed that $\alpha$ is parametrized by arclength, so $\alpha''(s)$ is parallel to the normal vector. Now do you know the vector form of a straightline?

Comment: What is a "cirle"? And what does "linear combination of curve" mean?

Comment: See also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2467488/counterexample-and-hint-to-solve-question-4-page-23-in-do-carmos-differential-g

Comment: @GerryMyerson cirle was a typo, should have been circle. Besides, with the linear combination I meant that P can be expressed in terms of $\alpha$ and $\alpha''$, with some $r(s)$

Comment: @lEm I suppose not, or I cannot see in what way it is used

Comment: If what you mean is "expressed in terms of $\alpha$ and $\alpha''$ with some $r(s)$", then you should write that, instead of the nonsensical "linear combination of a curve". Although I don't see why you can't just define $r(s)$ to be $(P-\alpha(s))/\alpha''(s)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson About your last phrase: we can't divide two vectors!

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ah, I agree that the phrasing of 'linear combination' is not the proper way to denote the equation of $P$. However, I think the question still is clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the curve is parametrized by arclencht, the normal vector is parallel to the normal vector. Therefore, for every $s$, the equation of the normal line to the curve passing through $\alpha(s)$ will be
$$\beta(r)=\alpha(s)+r\alpha''(s), \space \space r \in \mathbb{R}.$$

All of these lines passes through $P_0$. That means that, for each line, there will be a value of $r$, let's say $r_0$ that will satisfy
$$P_0=\alpha(s)+r_0\alpha''(s). \space \space \space (1)$$

Of course, this value of $r_0$ will depend of the normal line we are considering, and, therefore, will depend of the parameter $s$. We can rewrite $(1)$ to reinforce this dependence:
$$P_0=\alpha(s)+r_0(s)\alpha''(s).$$

And that's just your equation.